# Android Studio can't start git, although actually can

Tags: android, git, android-studio

My Android Studio is complaining about

Can't start Git: `/usr/bin/git`

Probably the path to Git executable is not valid

although I can actually use git in android studio, and `/usr/bin/git` works in terminal.

How do I get rid of this false error

Here is my ~/.bash_profile

`export PATH=/usr/bin/git:$PATH`

Comment: can you post the script?

Comment: please see my ~/.bash_profile

Comment: can you open the android-studio's preferences, look for the version control, expand it, and select git. There should be something like *Path to git executable*

Comment: /usr/bin/git, and when I test, git executed successfully. I can use git in android studio, just dunno why that error keeps appearing

Comment: can you post the result of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/git`. Are you on linux or mac ?

Comment: I am on mac and I am missing git in /usr/local/bin

Comment: can you post the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/git`? are you running AS as administrator or normal user ?

Comment: ls: /usr/local/bin/git: No such file or directory. I am running as normal user

Comment: again,  `ls -l /usr/bin/git` without local

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14160 Sep 29  2014 /usr/bin/git

Comment: I solved by installing a git at /usr/local/git/bin/git, so now I have two git, then in android studio I use /usr/local/git/bin/git. If you can answer as why android studio complains about git at /usr/bin/git, although git works with the error, I accept your answer

Comment: `/usr/local/git/bin/git` doesn't look that good. Can you create a symlink to git in `/usr/local/bin` ? To me it looks like AS has not enough permissions to access /user/bin

Comment: I symbol linked /usr/local/git/bin/git as /usr/local/bin/git, then in android studio I reference /usr/local/bin/git. Everything works, thank you. please write as a answer so I accept. I guess it is a bug that android studio error about git at /usr/bin, but actually could excute git at /usr/bin

Comment: [Refer for further clarifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661484/os-x-cant-start-git-usr-bin-git-probably-the-path-to-git-executable-is-not)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is probably a permission issue on AS side. You could try to symlink `/usr/bin/git` to `/user/local/bin/git` and make AS pointing to the symlink.

Comment: What are your symlink permissions?

Answer (score 57):

If you're on Mac OSX, run `sudo xcodebuild -license` in the Terminal. It will show a wall of text. Carefully read the license ;) and keep pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> until you reach the end and then simply type `agree` and hit enter. This fixed the above error for me on Android Studio.

On some occasions even that might not fix this issue. Try running the following command in the Terminal and restart Android Studio.

```
sudo /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: i tried but error....xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Comment: **`sudo /usr/bin/git` + Studio Restart** worked just like charm.

Answer (score 10):

Fixed it.. There was no Xcode installed on my mac.

Installed it from command line

```
xcode-select --install
```

It will ask for prompt to install accept and install

Then try

```
git --version
```

Answer (score 10):

In order to find the git path:

```
which git
```

Comment: None of the selected answers solved my problem except this one. Thanks @DoronK

Comment: I used above command and response was /usr/local/bin/git. I updated Android Studio to the above, clicked on Test button and got the 'Git executed successfully' message.

Answer (score 7):

After update **Xcode** to 7.0 my **Android Studio** complained about Git and the solution for me was go to terminal and type

```
 sudo /usr/bin/git
```

or

```
sudo git --version
```

This will show you this message:

> You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements.You must agree to
>   both license agreements below in order to use Xcode.

at the final you have to agree the license

> By typing 'agree' you are agreeing to the terms of the software
>   license agreements.

Answer (score 4):

First you need to accept the license

```
xcodebuild -license accept
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i downloaded an update of **Xcode** and didn't remember to Accept the New **License Agreement/Terms and Conditions**. So i just started the Xcode and Agreed to New License Agreement and it started working.