# OS X - Can't start Git: /usr/bin/git Probably the path to Git executable is not valid

Tags: git, macos, android-studio

I get this error in Android Studio:

> Can't start Git: /usr/bin/git
>              Probably the path to Git executable is not valid.

It gives me an option to fix it, where it takes me to the area in Android Studio to set the path to git. I see it is set to

> /usr/bin/git

And I check that path, and that path is indeed the path to the git executable. Why is Android Studio unable to start git?

**EDIT: When I try to use git commands in the Android Studio terminal it says:**

> Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please
>   re-run as root via sudo.

Comment: You haven't installed git on your mac yet haven't you ? If so, open a terminal, run git, it will ask you to install the dev suite and you'll get it.

Comment: @topheman Thanks. I've been using git on my mac for XCode projects and also Android Studio projects. Git was working in my Android Studio project last night. When I try to run git it says:

Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

Comment: Have you made an update on your mac ? When you run `which git` in the terminal, does it find it ? If you can't run git anymore, you should follow up and re-run as sudo

Comment: It was changed to /usr/local/lib/git

Comment: Since the Xcode command line needs to be updated, you have to run,`xcode-select --install`

Answer (score 217, accepted):

You should run `sudo git --version` on your command line.
It will ask you to agree to the git xcode license agreement, once done everything will work as before.

Comment: Did not work for me, I get the message "xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun". I will try and Google a solution for this and bring it here

Comment: @chucky I also faced same problem, then I ran "xcode-select --install" worked for me.

Comment: If agreeing to license's after running "xcode-select --install" and other commands, still the git does not work.   Try this 
 Step1 . Go to terminal on Android studio, and run
> which git 
it will give you the path to executable git which Android studio has permission to run. 
enter that path in "Path to git executable"  , click apply, and test it using the test button on right top.

Answer (score 98):

When upgrading to MacOS Sierra I had to run: `xcode-select --install`

Comment: I also had to use the solution indicated here, maybe because I didn't do "sudo xcode-select --install": https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241205-Mac-OSX-can-t-start-Git-after-updating-Mac-OS-XCode.

Answer (score 55):

I got this problem too, because I uninstalled my Xcode.

I solved it with these steps:

1. Type `xcode-select --install` in the terminal  (Installs the license)
2. Download a git and re-install it

After these 2 steps, I can use git commands in the terminal like `git` or `git --version`.

But when I open the android studio, it still show the error

so we need another two steps:

3. Type `which git` in your terminal (find out the git path)
4. Configure the path (you got in the step 3) in your android studio , then apply

Just like below pic
[image]

It works for me.

Comment: Saved the day! Phew... Thank you

Answer (score 47):

You should agree explicitly to user's licence agreement.

**This is how you should do it:**

1. Open terminal
2. run the following command: `sudo xcodebuild -license`
3. agree to the terms.

That's it! :)

Comment: If you don't like the terminal you can also open Xcode app and accept the terms.

Comment: If you recently upgraded Xcode, then typing `git` in the terminal will give you the message `Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please run “sudo xcodebuild -license” and then retry this command.` In that case this is the right answer for you.

Answer (score 13):

use "which git" in terminal.
It will provide you your git location. like "/usr/local/bin/git"
paste this location in popup which came after clicking "Fix it".
Then click apply.

Answer (score 9):

In terminal

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried "/usr/local/bin/git" path and clicked "Test" button but was getting error.

so I clicked on three dots besides Test button and jumped to the given path but there was no git executable present. So at below path I found git exec:

**/usr/local/git/bin/git**

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I met a same problem. 
Idea indicate that: Can't start Git: /user/bin/git...
And I run "which git" on terminate and I found that my git stay on: /user/local/bin/git
So what I need is change git's path on project setting.
And it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had updated Xcode last night. I ran git as root via sudo in the terminal and then it said I have not agreed to the Xcode licence terms, and allowed me to view them and then agree in the terminal. I probably would have got the GUI version if I tried to open Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

When I installed MacOS Sierra I ran `xcode-select --install` and it worked fine

Comment: This sounds like a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39649839).

Answer (score 3):

`sudo xcode-select --reset` in the terminal instantly solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

I my case I've changed the name of Xcode app to Xcode9 and renamed later to Xcode.

I needed to update my Xcode.app path.

After typing `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` on terminal everything worked fine again

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in PhpStorm. This came to me after updating XCode on OS X EL Capitan. After this update I didn't open it to accept the license that was necessary for XCode and OS X. When I had accept the license the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue when having two Xcode (ver.7 and ver.8) apps installed in my Mac OS Sierra.

What I do is simply open the Xcode 8, go to **Preferences**, select **Locations** in tab, and set the **Command Lines Tools** to **Xcode 8.0**.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run sudo git --version
2. If already Xcode is installed : Run sudo softwareupdate -ia --verbose
   If not : xcode-select --install
   sudo xcodebuild -license
3. sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

After this don’t forget to re-start the system. It worked for me and for sure work you you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Download git from  https://git-scm.com  after download install it and then **in terminal** type **which git** you will get git path

Satishs-MacBook-Air:~ Pathuri$ which git

/usr/local/bin/git

Satishs-MacBook-Air:~ Pathuri$

click on apply and fit it on the pop up it will solve .

Answer (score 0):

If you recently installed Jetbrains Toolbox:

Uninstall and installing through the Toolbox solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just run "**/usr/local/bin/git**" on terminal.

Answer (score 0):

At first try to restart your pc, if you just installed git.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried most of the options, try once running the below command.

```bash
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me:

1. Add gitlab/github account with access to this repository to Android Studio.
2. Choose account
3. Click on button set as Default.