# Reset Rstudio to find github on path

Tags: r, github, rstudio

I had to delete my hard drive and reinstall R,Rstudio and Github on my Mac. When setting up version control I clicked browse to look for git executable.  I see that I should have left it as the default `/usr/bin/git`. How can I get RStudio to reset to the default? I can't see to navigate to that folder.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OS X - Can't start Git: /usr/bin/git Probably the path to Git executable is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661484/os-x-cant-start-git-usr-bin-git-probably-the-path-to-git-executable-is-not)

Comment: Do you have `git` installed? Can you run it from the terminal? What does `which git` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find instructions for resetting RStudio's state here:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State